# How to solve $\ddot{x}=c_1 \dot{x}^2-c_2 x^{-2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

So I wanted to solve the differential equation that describes a ball falling with air drag and variable gravity (it depends on the height). Here's my procedure:
\begin{align*}
\sum F&= ma\\
m\ddot{h}&=F_d -F_g\\
\ddot{r}&=\frac{\kappa}{m}\dot{r}^2-\frac{GM}{r^2},
\end{align*}
where $r=R+h.$

The thing is I don't know how to solve it or even if it can be solved analitically...

Comment: If the distance is large enough to consider gravity as a function of height (as opposed to being roughly constant) would that also mean the fluid density should also be considered a function of height? Also, I found that considering $(R+h)''=\frac{\kappa}{m}(R+h)'^2-\frac{GM}{(R+h)^2}$ is equivalent to the original problem because the derivative of a constant is zero, so the substitution $u=R+h$ into the new equation gives the same problem without $R$.

Comment: Evidently, there is an explicit formula for $h$ if gravity is constant, though I haven't found anything when gravity is a considerable function of height.

Comment: Your point makes a lot of sense and is logical; a big failure on my part not to think about it, thank you. Concerning the other $R+h$ thing, that makes sense too.

Comment: We could even say that the density of air depends on temperature too, which at the same time depends on height.

Comment: In any way, I'll use this exponential approximation that I found on Wikipedia: $\rho=\rho_o e^{-\frac{h}{H_n}}$

Comment: Since this means including an exponential in the original diff. eq., I doubt it can be solved analytically. For now I'd prefer to solve the original one and then maybe solve the modified one numerically via Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with $\ddot{x} = c_1 \dot{x}^2 - \frac{c_2}{x^2}$, we can consider $v = \dot{x}$ as a function of $x$, which lets us do the following:

$\begin{eqnarray} \ddot{x} & = & \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} \\
& = & \frac{dv}{dt} \\
& = & \frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} \\
& = & \frac{dv}{dx} v \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx}\left(v^2\right)\end{eqnarray}$

So now our equation reduces to $\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dy}(v^2) = c_1 v^2 - c_2 x^{-2}$. We can then set $w = v^2$ and rearrange the equation to become $w' - 2 c_1 w = -2 c_2 x^{-2}$, which is an exact first order ODE. Unfortunately, its solution comes in the form of the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$, which does not bode well for our final expression.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The problem is that when I plot the expression that I got from WolframAlpha of the velocity, it ressembles x=constant (basically a vertical line).